# iFrame Height Code Not Working

Tags: canvas, facebook-iframe, facebook-canvas

I am trying to make my iFrame page height adjust to the content of the page.  In app settings I have set the following:

Canvas Width:Fixed (760px)
Canvas Height:Settable (Default: 800px)
Social Discovery:Enabled

And I this is the code for my index.html file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0              
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title></title><meta http-equiv="refresh" 
content="0;url= Merchandise.html" />
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.Canvas.setSize();}
function sizeChangeCallback() {
FB.Canvas.setSize();}
</script></head><body><div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({ 
appId : 'XXXXXXXXX',
status : true, 
cookie : true, 
xfbml : true 
});
</script></body></html>
```

Not really sure whats wrong from here.  Any help would be great.  I have also tried adding the css blocks that are recommended to no avail.

Removed the meta refresh tag, edited the code, now looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0     
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title></title><content="0;url=   
Merchandise.html" />
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload=function() {
  FB.Canvas.setSize({width:760,height:document.body.offsetHeight});
}
</script></head><body>
</body></html>
```

Still no luck

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to call FB.init() unless you are doing something else with the javascript SDK. Try getting rid of all the `<script>` blocks you currently have and put just this code in the `<head>`:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload=function() {
  FB.Canvas.setSize({width:760,height:document.body.offsetHeight});
}
</script>
```

But also, what's with the meta refresh tag in the header?

For a Page Tab, modify the call to setSize() like this:

```
FB.Canvas.setSize({width:520,height:document.body.offsetHeight+20});
```

Also be very sure that you don't have any elements in your page wider that 760px/520px, otherwise the horizontal scrollbar will appear which often makes the vertical one appear as well.

Comment: Check above, I edited the question with the new code, still no luck

Comment: What exactly does it do/not do? If you have just a test file with a few lines of text, does it shrink down? Might want to also give it a try with no css file specified, in case you have something in there tripping it up.

Comment: Everything displays correctly, it is just bound by the 800px height.  You can see it here: http://www.facebook.com/pages/DCS-Test/168731319885645?sk=app_296884996990186

Comment: I didn't realize you were talking about a page tab. Obviously, the 760 value needs to be reduced to 520, and you should also add a "fudge factor" of around 20px or so to the height. I have edited my answer with the necessary alterations.

Comment: Still won't remove the vertical bars.  The horizontal are gone.  I have no idea what I am doing wrong here, very frustrating.

Comment: Wow, 4.5 hours later, I finally figured it out.  Facebook wasn't looking through my index.html file.  I renamed it and reset it within the app settings and it worked.  Thanks for your help